# Changing connection string after Bind in Ninject

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, ninject

I have an MVC application using Ninject to connect to a single database. I have been asked to use a Login database to get the connection string for the data. This is so we can authenticate using a LoginDatabase and then go off somewhere else for the client data. This will allow us to have one website for all of our clients rather than the current setup of one webapp per client.

The issue we are having is that the we are already bound to the Login database by the time the application is loaded and the user is logged in. We need to be able to ReBind the Ninject part after the user has successfully logged in, I am pretty new to Ninject and this is currently kettling my head.

This is the code that is called on startup :

```
 private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
         var main = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainConnection"].ConnectionString;
        var mainKernel = new StandardKernel(new INinjectModule[]
        {
            new AllBindings(main)
        });
        mainKernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        mainKernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

        RegisterServices(mainKernel);
        return mainKernel;

    }
```

and the load function in AllBindings

```
public override void Load()
    {

        this.Bind<IScheduleItemRepository>().To<ScheduleItemRepository>().WithConstructorArgument("ConnectionString", _mainConnectionString);
        this.Bind<IOtherScheduleItemRepository>().To<OtherScheduleItemRepository>().WithConstructorArgument("myOptions", _mainConnectionString);
        this.Bind<IDocumentRepository>().To<DocumentRepository>().WithConstructorArgument("myOptions", _mainConnectionString);

    }
```

How am I best changing the connection string constructor argument in this case after I have returned it from the Login database?